# Javascript resize image after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, image, testing

How would I resize an html image with Javascript? I would like the "Pack" image to become larger after 7 seconds. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Pack -->
        <img id="pack" src="http://cloud.attackofthefanboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/fifa14pack.png">

        <!-- Sparkles-->
    <div id="sparkles">

        <img id="sparkle1" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle2" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle3" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle4" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle5" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle6" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle7" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle8" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">
        </div>
```

Comment: You have to show us what you have tried so far. Show us some of your JS code. Stackoverflow is not for others writing code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a timeout function to change the elements styles after 7 seconds with the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var pack = document.getElementById("pack");
    pack.style.width = "100%;";
}, 7000);
```

You will probably want to customize this to your use case.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to edit the positioning of the image after the resize, thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("pack").style.width="soandsopx";document.getElementById("pack").style.height="soandsopx";},7000);
```

Where "soandsopx" is the number of pixels you want it to have, plus "px".

Comment: It works great, I think I'm going to end up using this. It's short and gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var pack_image = document.getElementById('pack');
    if(pack_image && pack_image.style) {
        pack_image.style.height = '700px';
        pack_image.style.width = '700px';
    }
},7000);
```

**[jsFiddle of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ73J/1/)**

Comment: Do you know how I would edit the position of the image? I tried this: window.setTimeout(function () {
    var pack_image = document.getElementById('pack');
    if(pack_image && pack_image.style) {
        pack_image.style.height = '350px';
        pack_image.style.width = '250px';
        pack_image.style.top = '%50';
        pack_image.style.left = '%50';
    }
},7000);

Comment: It's nigh-impossible to answer that question without knowing what the rest of the CSS looks like.

Check out [this article on CSS positioning for more information](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: #pack {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px; 
    margin-left: -100px;
}

Comment: With the given ruleset you should be able to modify `top` and `left` to achieve what you want.  **[Here's an update to the jsFiddle from earlier, now only changing position](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ73J/2/)**.

Comment: Hmm. I have tried multiple times, it's only working for me once I remove the height and width animation.